# Send grid API key not working with oracle plsql

Tags: email, smtp, oracle-sqldeveloper, sendgrid, plsqldeveloper

I am having an issue regarding sending email through smtp_sendgrid in oracle plsql. I have an email stored procedure. When I use a normal username and password, it sends the email properly but when I use the API key, it causes the error '421 service not available'. This is critical because sendgrid is about to discard normal username and password and will use API key only. This API key is working fine in other applications but causing an error in plsql only.